# Formatting CSV With Parentheses To INSERT INTO Existing SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert

Let's say I have a table with the following rows/columns:

> ```
> ID Name Date
> 1 John 8/2/2021
> 2 Raj  8/3/2021
> ```

And I want to use the INSERT INTO statement to add multiple additional rows.

The problem I am running into is this:

The query needs to be written as follows:

```
INSERT INTO *table_name* (ID, Name, Date)
VALUES (3, Jake, 8/3/2021), (4, Steve, 8/5/2021)
```

However, the csv I need to import does not have brackets to terminate each row. Instead, it just starts a new line. It looks a little like this:

```
3, Jake, 8/3/2021
4, Steve, 8/5/2021
and so on...
```

I want to be able to copy the CSV and use it in my query, but I would have to add a parentheses at the start and end of each row.

This is a highly manual and time-consuming process, so I wanted to see if there's a quick fix before I went ahead and did it. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: `8/3/2021` is a numeric expression. Did you intend to write a date constant? If you did, then use a [universally understood format](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) that is always interpreted correctly.

Comment: It's not clear in your question *how* you are "importing" your csv - it's a file - normally you would load the file into a staging table with BCP, Bulkload or some other tool. In SQL Server 2019 you could use *polybase* and *ODBC* to query your csv file as if it were a table.

Comment: If you really want to do this as a an actual SQL query, you can open it in Excel, on the last column put `="(" + A1 + ",'" + B1 + "',"` etc, then drag that down the rest of the sheet

Comment: If you're actually pasting the text content into SSMS to write a query, if you can roughly align the data you can click and drag while holding left-alt key to edit over all the rows simultaneously, very quick to add brackets or commas to all rows; you could also just prefix each row with `insert into select` and suffix each with `union all`...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following ways:

1. By opening the file in Excel and do the changes as @Charlieface has
   suggested.
2. By opening the file directly into SSMS and perform the required
   multiline edit by holding `Alt+Shift` and pressing the arrow keys/tab
   to control the selection/position as @Stu has suggested.
3. You can open the file in EmEditor (if the file is too big) or in
   SSMS and perform the following replacement:

   replace newline (`\n`) with `') \n ,(`

   replace `,`(*comma space*) with `,'`

   regex replace `(,'\d)` with `'\1`

   edit the first and last row to add `insert into` and a closing
   bracket.